# How to apply the same conditional formatting to other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

My spreadsheet has multiple rows. Each row has a checkbox. If a checkbox is ticked, conditional formatting will highlight that row. I am curious to know if there's a way to apply the conditional format to the next 500 rows as if I'm just dragging down a formula which will reference the cells correctly.

I tried using the format painter, but all that does is extend the highlighted area if I were to tick a single checkbox. Conditional Format Rules Manager doesn't help my situation as the options are very limited. Copying and pasting just the formatting rules still just extends the highlight from a single row.

Comment: what's wrong with highlighting the 500 cells and adding a new rule? (same as the 1st rule).

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have a row set up the way you want,
   you should be able to select it and drag/fill down.
2. If you have a row or some other region/range set up the way you want,
   you can do “Conditional Formatting” → “Manage Rules”
   and change the “Applies to” range to the range you want to cover.
   [image: “Conditional Formatting” → “Manage Rules”]